# zend framework and php, increment only if set of values in both arrays are equal

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, zend-framework

I have 2 arrays. the first array contains the result of a database query. Essentially it is a database of information. the second array contains user defined values selected on a screen. my goal is reconcile certain elements that the user has clicked with the database result set. the end result i am trying to achieve is the following "rule": if a group of elements match a certain group from each array, id like to increment a counter. not all key values need to match, only certain ones. for example if the DB result array contains 3 values, and the user array contains only 2 matching values then do NOT increment. if the db result array contains 3 values, and the user array contains all 3 matching values then DO increment.

an example of each multidimensional array is provided:

```
//DB results - $result()
Array ( 

   [0] => Array ( 
      [id] => 115 
      [q_id] => question-1 
      [course_id] => 1 
      [course_section] => unit-2-section-2 
      [a_id] => question-1-drop-down-answer-1-input 
      [a_body] => August [answer] => yes 
      [timestamp] => 2014-11-30 21:36:02 
   ) 
[1] => Array ( 
      [id] => 117 
      [q_id] => question-1 
      [course_id] => 1 
      [course_section] => unit-2-section-2 
      [a_id] => question-1-drop-down-answer-3-input [a_body] => 10 
      [answer] => yes [timestamp] => 2014-11-30 21:36:02 
) 
[2] => Array ( 
      [id] => 119 
      [q_id] => question-1 
      [course_id] => 1 
      [course_section] => unit-2-section-2 
      [a_id] => question-1-drop-down-answer-5-input 
      [a_body] => 2013 [answer] => yes [timestamp] => 2014-11-30 21:36:02 
) 
[3] => Array ( 
      [id] => 136 
      [q_id] => question-2 
      [course_id] => 1 
      [course_section] => unit-2-section-2 
      [a_id] => question-2-drop-down-answer-1-input 
      [a_body] => December [answer] => yes 
      [timestamp] => 2014-11-30 21:36:02 
) 
[4] => Array ( 
      [id] => 139 
      [q_id] => question-2 
      [course_id] => 1 
      [course_section] => unit-2-section-2 
      [a_id] => question-2-drop-down-answer-4-input 
      [a_body] => 23 
      [answer] => yes 
      [timestamp] => 2014-11-30 21:36:02 
) 
[5] => Array ( 
      [id] => 141 
      [q_id] => question-2 
      [course_id] => 1 
      [course_section] => unit-2-section-2 
      [a_id] => question-2-drop-down-answer-6-input 
      [a_body] => 1984 
      [answer] => yes 
      [timestamp] => 2014-11-30 21:36:02 
) 
[6] => Array ( 
      [id] => 149 [q_id] => question-3 
      [course_id] => 1 
      [course_section] => unit-2-section-2 
      [a_id] => question-3-drop-down-answer-1-input 
      [a_body] => Febraury 
      [answer] => yes 
      [timestamp] => 2014-11-30 21:36:02 
) 
[7] => Array ( 
      [id] => 150 
      [q_id] => question-3 
      [course_id] => 1 
      [course_section] => unit-2-section-2 
      [a_id] => question-3-drop-down-answer-2-input 
      [a_body] => 14 
      [answer] => yes 
      [timestamp] => 2014-11-30 21:36:02 
      ) 
)

//User input array - $dataAnswers()
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
                [questionID] => question-1 
                [courseID] => 1 
                [courseSection] => unit-2-section-2 
                [questionType] => select-all 
                [selectedAnswer] => August 
        ) 

        [1] => Array ( 
                [questionID] => question-2 
                [courseID] => 1 
                [courseSection] => unit-2-section-2 
                [questionType] => select-all 
                [selectedAnswer] => December 
        ) 
        [2] => Array ( 
                [questionID] => question-3 
                [courseID] => 1 
                [courseSection] => unit-2-section-2 
                [questionType] => select-all 
                [selectedAnswer] => Febraury 
        ) 
        [3] => Array ( 
                [questionID] => question-3 
                [courseID] => 1 
                [courseSection] => unit-2-section-2 
                [questionType] => select-all 
                [selectedAnswer] => 14 
        ) 
)
```

here is my first attempt but i just cant seem to wrap my head around this logically. any suggestion would be greatly appreciated:

```
//counters
    $i = 0; 
    $f = 0; 

    foreach ($dataAnswers as $a){

        $e = 0;

        foreach ($result as $r){

            if ($a['questionID'] == $r['q_id']) {
                $e++;
            }

            if ($a['questionID'] == $r['q_id'] && $a['selectedAnswers'] == $r['a_body']) {
                $f++;
            }

            if($e == $f){
                $i++;
            }

        }


    }
```

I should conclude that the above example is expected to provide a value of $i = 1.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this: `if the DB result array contains 3 values, and the user array contains only 2 matching values then do NOT increment. if the db result array contains 3 values, and the user array contains all 3 matching values then DO increment.`, please give some examples.

Comment: not every element in the DB $result array needs to match the user $dataAnswers array. in my example above, you can see that there are 3 entries in $result with the q_id= 'question-1'. but only 1 entry in $dataAnswers with that same ID. therefore because the count of each similar dimension is different, i would NOT increment the counter. similarly, for q_id = 'question-3' the counts match, there are 2 entries in $result and 2 entries in $dataAnswers, so the count would increment by 1

Comment: `there are 3 entries in $result with the q_id= 'question-1'. but only 1 entry in $dataAnswers with that same ID`.... no, there are 3 entries in `$dataAnswers` with `questionID` equals `question-1`, they are index 0,1, and 2 in `$dataAnswers`. Your statement doesn't make sense.

Comment: edited my question... seems like it was a cut ans paste error, my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to create two arrays and count how many elements with the same key have the same value between those two arrays. The first array (`$res`) contains all `q_id` values from `$result` as the key and the count of each `q_id` value as the corresponding values. Here's what `$res` would look like if we use your example:

```
Array {
  [question-1] => 3
  [question-2] => 3
  [question-3] => 2
}
```

The second array (`$ans`) contains all `questionID` values from `$dataAnswers` as the key and the count of matching elements of each `questionID` value as the corresponding values. Here's what `$ans` would look like based on your example:

```
Array {
  [question-1] => 1
  [question-2] => 1
  [question-3] => 2
}
```

You can see from the above two arrays that only the third element with key equals `question-3` has the same value, so you get your expected count, which is 1. Below is the complete code that implements the above idea. The counter that you're looking for is `$matching_count`.

```
// get all q_id from $result and its count
$res = Array();
foreach ($result as $r){
    if (array_key_exists($r['q_id'], $res)) {
        $res[$r['q_id']]++;
    }
    else {
        $res[$r['q_id']] = 1;
    }
}

// get all questionID from $dataAnswers
$ans = Array();

foreach ($dataAnswers as $a){
    if (!array_key_exists($a['questionID'], $ans)) {
        $ans[$a['questionID']] = 0;
    }
}

foreach ($dataAnswers as $a){
    foreach ($result as $r){
        if ($a['questionID'] == $r['q_id'] && $a['selectedAnswer'] == $r['a_body']) {
            // increase the count in $ans
            $ans[$a['questionID']]++;
        }
    }
}

// check how many elements of $ans have the same value as $res with the same key
$matching_count = 0;
foreach ($ans as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $res)
        && $ans[$key] == $res[$key]) {
        $matching_count++;
    }
}

echo $matching_count;
```

Output

```
1
```

Working demo: http://codepad.org/5EzYaB8l

Comment: this is really good... BUT there is a component missing. if $dataAnswers has more entries then the $result, the count should not be incremented. example: $res['q_id] = 2, $ans['questionID'] = 3, the $matching_count should not increment. remember the $ans array is user input, so it can be dynamic. once this part is fixed your answer will be marked as right

Comment: Ok it's fixed now, I added an extra `questionID` (`question-4`) to `$dataAnswers` in the codepad demo and it produces `1` as the output. I hope it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

For record purposes, here is the exact solution i ended up employing. thank you @ekad for guiding me in the right direction. I will still mark yours as correct however. thank you

```
// get all q_id from $result and its count
    $res = Array();
    foreach ($result as $r){
        if (array_key_exists($r['q_id'], $res)) {
            $res[$r['q_id']]++;
        }
        else {
            $res[$r['q_id']] = 1;
        }
    }

    // get all questionID from $dataAnswers and its count
    $ansCount = Array();
    foreach ($dataAnswers as $a){
        if (array_key_exists($a['questionID'], $ansCount)) {
            $ansCount[$a['questionID']]++;
        }
        else {
            $ansCount[$a['questionID']] = 1;
        }
    }


    //get all questionID from $dataAnswers
    $ans = Array();     
    foreach ($dataAnswers as $a){
        if (!array_key_exists($a['questionID'], $ans)) {
            $ans[$a['questionID']] = 0;
        }
    }       

    foreach ($dataAnswers as $a){
        foreach ($result as $r){
            if ($a['questionID'] == $r['q_id'] && $a['selectedAnswer'] == $r['a_body']) {

                // increase the count in $ans
                $ans[$a['questionID']]++;

            }

        }
    }    

    $matching_count = 0;
    foreach ($ansCount as $key => $value){
        if ($ansCount[$key] == $res[$key]) {

            if ($ans[$key] == $res[$key]) {
                $matching_count++;
            }

        }
    }

    echo $matching_count;
```